# Running Java application doing nothing

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ctakes

I am new to Java

and I have done every possible scenario I could find or think of

This is an open source code that I got for the ineternet for my study

https://github.com/healthnlp/examples/tree/gh-pages

I tried to run the code through maven install / test

from the Run menu and nothing happens

I tried to google and search SOF for solutions but found nothing that can help me

I read about IntelliJ and Java but was way to advanced for me and I am running out of time for my study project.

So I hope I can find the answer here.

this is the IDE I use

[image]

and pom code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
    <artifactId>ctakes-temporal-demo</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <name>ctakes-temporal-demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description></description>
    <properties>
        <ctakes.version>4.0.0</ctakes.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jettyVersion>9.2.6.v20141205</jettyVersion>
    </properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>apache.snapshots</id>
    <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- cTAKES module versions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-type-system</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-core-res</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-res</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-preprocessor</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-pos-tagger</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-pos-tagger-res</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-chunker</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-chunker-res</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-lvg</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-lvg-res</artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-context-tokenizer
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-clinical-pipeline
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ne-contexts
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-ne-contexts-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-zoner
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-assertion-zoner-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-constituency-parser
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-constituency-parser-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-coreference
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-coreference-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-drug-ner
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-drug-ner-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-side-effect
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-side-effect-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-smoking-status
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-smoking-status-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-dependency-parser
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-dependency-parser-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-relation-extractor
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                    ctakes-relation-extractor-res
                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                                        ctakes-temporal
                                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                                        ctakes-temporal-res
                                </artifactId>
            <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
            <artifactId>uimaj-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
            <artifactId>uimafit-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ctakes-web-client</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
         <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <name>ctakesversion</name>
              <value>${ctakes.version}</value>
            </systemProperty>
         </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I just want to run the demo

[image]

Comment: Maven install or test dont run the app code. Find the class with public static main(), and click the green arrow next to it

Comment: @Andrejs there is no main in the whole system !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you are looking at is a Servlet<sup>1</sup> designed to run in a web container.  So, naturally, when you try to run it in your IDE as if it was a regular Java application, there is nothing to run.

To run the project, follow the instructions in the `index.md` file.

Alternatively, install Jetty locally and manually deploy the WAR file generated by the Maven build to it.

---

<sup>1 - I was originally confused by the fact that you didn't link to the "top" of the project.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a Jetty plugin in the project. In that case, all you have to do is use it to start the project:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Take a look at the documentation [Jetty docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.22.v20170531/maven-and-jetty.html)